# Docusign: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='none', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

I have successfully generated code via `get_authorization_uri` (at localhost). But when I try following:

`token = api_client.generate_access_token(client_id, client_secret, code)`

With python SDK **docusign_esign** it gives me following error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='none', port=443): Max retries exceeded with
> url: /oauth/token

But when I copy `generate_access_token` and its dependent functions in my custom class it works fine and return token.
Please note that I called `rest_client` in my copied function via `ApiClient()` it works fine, see at [rest_client](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-python-client/blob/3921a4ccdcd234ad619d72df8605940e3e45b03c/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py#L787)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Inbar Gazit kindly check this out!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not specifying the auth URL before trying to generate the token.

You should be doing a POST to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

in the error message, it shows that host = 'none'

The host should be account-d.docusign.com or https://account-d.docusign.com

This link will help you with Python SDK authentication: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/python/auth/